# How to split a datetime column in to two columns of Date and time separately in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I have a datetime column.

I want two columns: a date and a time column.

How can I split my column into two?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `time` type.  Please provide more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't say "PL/SQL" if you don't know what that means. If you think you do, you are mistaken; do a quick search online to see what it really means. I removed the `plsql` tag and I changed your title to say "Oracle SQL" instead of "PL/SQL".

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- a `DATE` data-type with the time component set to midnight for the date (you can enforce this with a check constraint); and
- an `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND` data-type for the time component.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  datetime_column DATE,
  date_column DATE,
  time_column INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND,
  CONSTRAINT table_name__date_column__chk CHECK (date_column = TRUNC(date_column))
)
```

If you want to get the combined date-time then you can easily add the two to get back to a date-time value.

> How can I split my column into two?

Assuming you have the columns you can use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET date_column = TRUNC(datetime_column),
    time_column = (datetime_column - TRUNC(datetime_column)) DAY TO SECOND;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a78305867858c2ef51cda25d7ae64264)*

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon commented, there's no `time` datatype in Oracle.

Though, literally answering what you asked, you *can* separate date and time and store each of them into their own columns - it's just that these will be `VARCHAR2` columns and you can only look at how pretty they are. You can't, for example, do any date arithmetic on them; first you'd have to convert them back to `date` datatype, so question is what you really want to do with what you get.

Anyway, here you are:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (datum      date,
  3     date_only  varchar2(10),
  4     time_only  varchar2(8)
  5    );

Table created.
```

Sample value:

```
SQL> insert into test (datum) values (sysdate);

1 row created.
```

Split date to two parts:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    date_only = to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
  3    time_only = to_char(datum, 'hh24:mi:ss');

1 row updated.
```

What's in there?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM               DATE_ONLY  TIME_ONL
------------------- ---------- --------
05.08.2021 21:05:06 05.08.2021 21:05:06

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no specific datatype for `time`, here my suggestion would be to keep the *datetime* in main column and add two `VIRTUAL COLUMN` for *date value* and *time value* respectively.

Oracle 11g has introduced a new feature that allows you to create a `VIRTUAL COLUMN`, an empty column that contains a function upon other table columns (the function itself is stored in the data dictionary).

However, it all depends on what you are going to do with it.
Please elaborate your requirement so that you will get a more specific answer.